# Change DateTime culture info for specific datetime input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, data-annotations

I am struggling with this for hours,
I have model with this property

```
public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
```

I display this property in View with changed format

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.ValidTo, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}" })
```

And the problem begin when I submit the form, 
because the property `Model.ValidTo` has now value `dd/MM/yyyy`. The day and month switched position. It should be `MM/dd/yyyy`.

How to map my custom date format in the view to the date format in the model ? Can I set custom date format in the model ? I cannot set culture for the whole page, I need to do it only for one model or better do it to specific datetime property in the model.

Any idea ?

**Experiment 1 - Custome Model Data Binder - Does not work**

I tried solution from this answer [DisplayFormat ApplyFormatInEditMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253964/displayformat-applyformatineditmode)

```
[DateTimeFormat(Format = "dd.MM.yyyy")]
        public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }

 public class DateTimeFormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string Format { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return true;

            DateTime val;
            try
            {
                val = DateTime.ParseExact(value.ToString(), Format, null);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //Not entirely sure it'd ever reach this, but I need a return statement in all codepaths
            return val != DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
```

but in the View, default datetime format is displayed and after submitting `dd.MM.yyyy` format, the model behave the same.

Comment: You will need to create a custom model binder

Comment: @StephenMuecke I tried but with no success, don't know what I am doing wrong :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Culture in an ASP.Net MVC app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add annotation :

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

Comment: I tried it before, but it does not work. DataFormatString seems to not apply.

Comment: This is a WebForms field.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I ment in the View and also in the Model.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I solved it with this way

In model, change model `DateTime` property to `string`

```
public string ValidTo { get; set; }
```

In controller

```
 DateTime dateTime;
 if (!DateTime.TryParse(model.ValidTo, 
     CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("cs-CZ"), 
     DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
 {
      ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "ValidTo date field is not valid.");
 }

 model.ValidTo = dateTime.ToString(); // optional, it depends on the use later

 if (ModelState.IsValid) {  ... }
```

Comment: Not a good idea. Your original problem was caused by a hard-coded locale (the server's). A request's locale is governed by the browser settings (eg preferred language), page settings, configuration settings or they can be set dynamically, eg per user, or based on a route (the `/en-US/` snippet you see in URLs). If you know the correct locale, set it per request

Comment: but, why do I need to know the requests locale ? I want show this specific locale (it goes as a string to the view and as a string back to the model) to all users, therefore it is hard coded

Comment: The duplicate question shows almost *all* the ways you can change the locale dynamically, based on routes, domains, user preferences etc

Comment: All users -> set it in web.config then. Your problem was caused because you use a US locale, or your server does, and your web.config doesn't have a locale specified. Check the `globalization` element

Comment: But, I need this specific input to be shown with different locale than is the locale of the web page. I am good with US locale because the whole page is in English, but I need to change locale only in this specific one input control in the view.

Comment: In this case I'd use a date picker control or script and ensure the date is sent as ISO8601 (2016-11-14), not as the displayed format. You should *avoid* hard-coding formats as much as possible to avoid conversion errors. .NET recognizes and parses the ISO format directly